# SSRS - Search entire Row for a Value - and highlight if found

Tags: reporting-services

The Query behind an SSRS report puts the Text "XXX" in fields that *should* have a value but do not.

When the report runs, I want all Cells that have "XXX" in them to be highlighted a certain color.

I have this Expression in the BackgroundColor Property of one of the fields:

```
=IIF(Fields!County.Value = "XXX", "DarkSalmon","Transparent")
```

and it is working fine.

Do I have to put that expression in every field I am checking - or can I use one expression that will look at every field in the row and highlight any that have "XXX" in them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need select all cells for putting your expression

Please check this [example](http://codinghelpers.net/ssrs-fill-an-entire-row-with-expression/)

Comment: Your example will not work for me. I need to search the entire row and then highlight only the fields in the row that have "XXX" in them. Your example searches one field in the row - and highlights the entire row if it finds the value. Thanks, though!

Comment: ohh ok, sorry.. so.. yes you need to put an expression in every field. regards

Comment: but you can select every cell that needs checking and then set the expression once for all selected cells.